# Why do I get error `Failed to load resource` on the client?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I  have this element in my index.cshtml page:

```
 <section class="parallax parallax-2 padding-xxs" style="background-image: url('mySiteName/assets/images/shutterstoc/img1.jpg');">
     <div>some content </div> 
</section>
```

As you can see I have style attribute.

If I change style attribute to this:

```
style="background-image: url('~/assets/images/shutterstoc/img1.jpg');"
```

The background image is disappear and I get this error in web console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)  img1.jpg
```

**Update*

```
The path to the image is:
http://localhost/assets/images/shutterstoc/img1.jpg
As you can see the mySiteName is missing.
```

Update2:
I try this path:

```
<section class="parallax parallax-2 padding-xxs" style="background-image: url('./assets/images/img1.jpg')">
```

But still I get error above. 
Why do I get error `Failed to load resource` and how to fix it?

Comment: why `~` and not `.` ?

Comment: just use ` . ` instead

Comment: what the meaning of the point?

Comment: `.` mean current location

Comment: please see, still I get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tilda sign `~` can be used in razor views to get the app root path. It will not work for css style sheet files.

When razor executes the view, if it finds the `~` , it will be converted to the app root base path.

Just use the path without the `~`

```
 background-image: url('./assets/images/shutterstoc/img1.jpg');
```

The image url is **relative the stylesheet**. So adjust the prefix `.` to `../` as needed depending on your location of the style sheet and the assets directory.

```
.someCssClass {
     background-image: url('./assets/images/shutterstoc/img1.jpg'); 
}
```

Like i mentioned above, the image location is **relative to the the location of the style sheet** . If you hard code the style in the view/page, it will be relative to the page's url. So while the request `yourSiteBaseUrl/` works , neither `yourSiteBaseUrl/Home/` or `yourSiteBaseUrl/Home/Index` won't work, **even though those 2 routes return the same action method and view/page**. So i recommend not doing that.

Move the definition to the css file and use the correct relative path there tot he image location. It will then work for `yourSiteBaseUrl/Home/Index` and `yourSiteBaseUrl/Home` and `yourSiteBaseUrl`

Comment: What you mean ?

Comment: @Michael `.` means current folder and `..` means parent folder

Comment: @Michael see your console and check the path you get by hovering on the image, you will see the absolute path used

Comment: like i mentioned in the answer, the image location is relative the location of the style sheet file. **If you hard code the style in the view/page, it will be relative to the page**.  So while `yourSiteBase/Home/` works , `yourSiteBase/Home/Index` won't work, even though both routes return the same view/page. So i recommend not doing that. Move it to your css file.